# Update keypairs in one json file with another json using jq (at another level)

Tags: json, object, merge, edit, jq

I have two files:

```
aws.json:
{
  "access_key_id": "MYSECRETKEYID",
  "secret_access_key": "mysecretaccesskey"
}



model.json:
{
    "access_key_id": "FREDSACCESSKEY",
    "secret_access_key": "fredssecretaccesskey",
    "ntp_servers_string": "1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8",
    "metrics_ip": null,
    "pagerduty_enabled": false,
    "blobstore_type": "s3",
    "s3_blobstore_options": {
        "endpoint": "https://s3.amazonaws.com",
        "bucket_name": "s3-mybucket",
        "access_key_id": "vault-supplied-key",
        "secret_access_key": "vault-supplied-key",
        "signature_version": "4",
        "region": "us-east-1"
    },
    "database_type": "external"
}
```

and I would like to use jq to update a couple of values in the s3_blobstore_options key to the end result is this:

```
result.json:

{
    "access_key_id": "FREDSACCESSKEY",
    "secret_access_key": "fredssecretaccesskey",
    "ntp_servers_string": "1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8",
    "metrics_ip": null,
    "pagerduty_enabled": false,
    "blobstore_type": "s3",
    "s3_blobstore_options": {
        "endpoint": "https://s3.amazonaws.com",
        "bucket_name": "s3-mybucket",
        "access_key_id": "MYSECRETKEYID",
        "secret_access_key": "mysecretaccesskey",
        "signature_version": "4",
        "region": "us-east-1"
    },
    "database_type": "external"
}
```

The following code works perfectly, if the values are not nested:

`jq --argfile override aws.json '. + $override' model.json > result.json`

Anyone know how to tell jq that I want to update the lower-level keys pairs, and not touch the upper level ones (i.e. `FREDSACCESSKEY`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply run:

```
jq --argfile aws aws.json '.s3_blobstore_options += $aws' model.json
```

Or if the jq filter is in aws.jq:

```
jq --argfile aws aws.json -f aws.jq model.json
```

The idea here is that when applying `+` to JSON objects, the values in the RHS object take precedence.

There are other ways for the jq program to access the contents of aws.json ...

Comment: Thanks! the first option works great! (not sure what aws.jq is, that fails on my machine)